# SQL/DBF Updating records from one table to another table located in different folder (*.dbf)

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, dbf

Updating records from one table to another table located in different folder.

```
Dim connection As New ADODB.Connection
Dim strConnection As String
Dim pathPrincipal As String
Dim pathUpdate As String 'External data base to update with TablePrincipal
Dim strSQL As String

pathPrincipal = "D:\DBFs"
strConnection = "Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=" & PathPrincipal 

connection.Open strConnection
If connection.State <> adStateOpen Then Exit Sub
```

'Correct :)

```
strSQL="UPDATE TablePrincipal#DBF" & " A INNER JOIN " & "TableUpdate#DBF" & " B ON A.ID = B.ID SET A.X=B.X, A.Y=B.Y"
'Execute 
connection.Execute strSQL, n, adCmdText
```

PREVIOUS CODE WORKS TO PERFECTION.....

BUT MY PROBLEM IS WHEN BOTH DBF NOT IN THE SAME FOLDER BUT I AM TRYING THIS IS NOT WHAT ELSE DO

```
'No working for external DBF :'( :(
strSQL = "UPDATE TablePrincipal#DBF A INNER JOIN" & _
         " OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)}; DBQ=" & _
         pathUpdate & "; SourceType = DBF ','SELECT * FROM TableUpdate#DBF') B" & _
         " ON A.ID=B.ID SET A.X=B.X, A.Y=B.Y"
```

ANYONE CAN HELP ME.....PLEASEEEE!!!! HELP
APOLOGIES FOR MY ENGLISH :)

Answer (score 0):

If the data resides on different volumes such as C:, D:, X:, Y: (or whatever mapping) you are pretty much out of luck without some adjustments...

I don't know about your path settings, but I know I've done the following working with VFP (Visual FoxPro) and using the latest OleDB Provider...

When making the connection for the data files,  you SHOULD be able to reference a relative path from the connection point. However, this would only work if the data paths you are referring to are BOTH on the same logical volume... 
such as

```
C:\SomePath\YourApplication\FirstDataFolder
C:\SomePath\YourApplication\SecondDataFolder

or even

C:\SomeOtherPath\AnotherDataLocation
```

if the above is SIMILAR to what your environment is, you could create a connection to
C:\SomePath\YourApplication

Then, your query should be able to do something like

```
update FirstDataFolder\YourTable A
   JOIN SecondDataFolder\YourOtherTable B
     on a.field = b.field
   set ... etc
   where
```

If the path is based on the third path sample, you would have to make your connection to C:\ by itself, then fully qualify the now "relative" paths to your data, such as:

```
update SomePath\YourApplication\FirstDataFolder\YourTable A
   JOIN SomeOtherPath\AnotherDataLocation\YourOtherTable B
     on a.field = b.field
   set ... etc
   where
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use full file names (including path) in your UPDATE and SELECT queries.